# How to do Show "Recent Items" from WinForm app

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I have a question regarding "Recent Items", almost all the applications that are fixed in the taskbar, when you press right click, they show you recent items. I have a windows form application made in visual studio and what I want is to show me "Recent Items" when the application is pinned to the taskbar. Does anyone know how to do this from visual studio?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Although you didn't say exactly what program you created one, I believe these two can help you.[Jumplist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and  [SHAddToRecentDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shaddtorecentdocs?redirectedfrom=MSDN)